# Has the license changed for the parts of BOOST that have been accepted into C++11?

Tags: c++, licensing

The Boost Software Library is licensed under the [BOOST License](http://www.boost.org/users/license.html)

Now, if you only use C++11, does this mean you're bound by the BOOST license terms if you use those parts of C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The Boost license covers their *code*. Only the *specification* of the code is part of the standard. Given how liberal the Boost license is, it's *possible* a library vendor could incorporate it into their implementation of the standard -- that's pretty much between you and your vendor though. There's undoubtedly some license on the code in your standard library, and chances are pretty good that it's already more restrictive than the Boost license in any case.

The important point, however, is to separate the specification from the code (Boost or otherwise) that implements that specification. The standard incorporates only the specification, but the Boost license covers only the code.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Boost to get C++11 features, then you're subject to the Boost license.  If your compiler comes with C++11 features, then you're subject to the license for your compiler toolchain.